# Let $p$ be a prime number. Show that if there exist $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p=3k+1$, then there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p=6n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. Show that if there exist  $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that p=3k+1, then there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p=6n+1$.

Comment: Show that if $k$ is odd, then $p$ is even

Comment: $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ means $p \equiv 1$ or $4 \bmod 6$

Answer (score 1):

Hint

- $p\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $p\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, so by [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)   .....

Answer (score 1):

k need to be even. (If k is odd then p would be even). So $k=2*n$ , and then $p=3k+1=3*2*n+1=6n+1$ . n would be then this number. Daniel